# Can I create web-service in C# without Visual Studio .net

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio

I want to create a web service. I dont have visual studio installed on my machine. Can I still create the web service using some other free software or should I make it in other language like java or php.

Comment: visual studio express is free.

Comment: There may be some reason he/she doesn't/can't have it installed.

Comment: I wasn't aware of Visual studio express.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you prefer to use C# there are several free alternatives including [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products) and [Sharp Develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/). And there's even [Mono Develop](http://monodevelop.com/).

And you don't even need an IDE. You can use a text editor like Notepad++, [see here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/notepad-c-compiler-you-can-do), and use the command line compiler CSC which comes with .NET runtimes.

Comment: Or even Notepad! And then you wouldn't have to install anything!

Comment: @user2129794: Glad I could be of help.

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Yup, i agree. NPP made it in with the 2nd edit. :-)

Comment: well one more thing... if I use Visual Studio Express that its free only for 30 days?? After that i would not be able to use it??

Comment: @user2129794: After 30 days you just have to register. It is still free.

Comment: ohhkk...forgot to see that in hurry.